# How to change where Nautilus mounts network drives (Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit)

Tags: networking, nautilus, mount, gvfs

When I mount a samba network share in nautilus it is mounted under `~/.gvfs`
I would like to change this default so that all network shares mounted using nautilus are mounted under `/mnt` for example.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there isn't a way. You can link ~/.gvfs to your home folder(~/shares or /mnt even) if you wanted.

Comment: When running compilation scripts with cmake within these linked folders, the symlink isn't respected and the original mangled path is used, which breaks cmake.  Mounting is a solution but mounting requires root access.  The allow_root option is mysteriously ignored. Strongly considering dropping support for gvfs